# Create directory in php avoiding 777 permission

Tags: php

I have a php script that is used to create different directories for different users to store their images.
One way to do this is use 777 permision like this:

```
$path = 'images/product/'.$pid;
if( ! file_exists($path)) {
    $mask=umask(0);
    mkdir($path, 0777);
    umask($mask);
}
```

Is there any other alternative that doesn't involve to use 777 permision for the directory, for example to set the file owner and group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the file owner/group requires privileges that your Apache should not have if you want to run it safely.
However, you don't necessarily need 0777. I guess you are storing images, so you can use 0644!

Side note: `chgrp()` and `chown()` are the 2 functions giving you the ability to change file group/owner

Comment: any chance do you know how to set file permission in windows shared hosting.